# Firestore subcollection querying and applying Firestore rules

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular5

**The situation:**

I am creating a data structure that basically looks like this:

```
events:
  adminUserId: 1337
  users:
    questiongroups:
      questions:
        text: 'foo',
        value: 42
```

So events is a list, same goes for users per event, questiongroups per user per event, and questions per questiongroups per user per event. Some of them have additional fields like IDs and such but I omitted them for the sake of simplicity.

This data structure is fine as far as I can restrict access in a way that only allows users to manipulate their own list of questiongroups and sublist of questions - with the firestore rules.

**The problem:**

Each event has an admin user that should be able to CRUD all the data for which he is the admin for (via the adminUserId). Or to be more precise, he should be able to see all that data in one big table in his UI for one event. It's a small scale application with roughly 20 users and maybe 50 questiongroups that have an average of 5 questions. So basically like that:

```
        | QuestionGroup1_Question1 | QuestionGroup1_Question2 | QuestionGroup2_Question1
user #1 | foo                      | bar                      | 1337
user #2 | foo                      | bar                      | 1701
```

Now I would like to be able to query the data of one event with the least amount of queries (possibly just one).
But from what I have gathered so far is that you can only execute shallow queries on Firestore, so I can only retrieve the fields of 'events' but would then have to query for each user, then query for each questiongroup and then again query for each question - which even with such small numbers would amount to a big number of queries.

So basically my question is: What are my options here? 
I have read that one could nest complex objects within documents. But according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data you can't query on them, so could I still restrict access via the Firestore rules on them? I found that you could do that with wildcards when using the Firebase realtime databse, but what about Firestore?

I'd be happy to learn about some options.
Thanks!

Comment: This is very broad.  It sounds like you're entering into a conversation where there may be many possibilities to discuss.  Posting to firebase-talk is likely more appropriate for this kind of discussion. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Comment: Basically my question is if I'd go for the nested data approach - like "event_1":{ "user_1":{...}, "user_2": {...}} - could I still apply Firestore rules to them? Like only allowing access to a user's data to the specific user himself and the admin - since I can't just query for a specific event and get all its sub data

Answer (score 0):

## Answers to your questions:

### Can you query on nested data? Yes

You can query on nested data, but not nested lists. You can mimic a list while still using an object (i.e. `{ 0: 'first', 1: 'second' }`), but I don't suggest that.

Here is an example of querying on nested data:
`db.collection('questions').where('topic.coding', '==', true)`

### Can you enforce rules on nested data? No (for reads)

You can not enforce read rules on nested data inside of a Firestore Document. That would require the ability to use `select` (only available in firebase-admin right now) and being able to see the request info in the rules similar to `request.query`([request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#properties)).

**Edit: Also, Yes (for writes)**
You can enforce write rules on all data (including nested objects and lists) for writes. Since you can see the entire payload for a write ([request.resource](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#resource)), you can then make rules determining what paths are overwrite-able and/or what values are allowed based on other data in the document or database.

## My suggestion

Flatten your database structure. Something like:

```
match /events/{event_id} {
  match /users/{user_id} {
  }
  match /groups/{group_id} {
  }
  match /questions/{question_id} {
    // check if request.auth.uid is creator
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what's in each of the documents, so I can't be for sure the best way of implementing your Firestore structure to allow for optimized querying and simplified rules.

Since Firestore rules don't cascade like Firebase's RTDB rules, flattening the structure doesn't complicate your rules at all. The only downside (which I consider an upside) is needing an index for non-shallow queries on the flattened collections (i.e. a user wanting to see all of their questions on the topic 'coding').

My final suggestion is to find out **what are all the possible query constraints** (i.e. user_id, topic, group_id), **determine which are mandatory** (maybe user_id and/or group_id), and **nest collections based on mandatory constraints** (i.e. /users/{user_id}/questions/{q_id} if "user_id" is mandatory for querying questions). For rules, you can always just add a sub-collection to the document needing security containing nothing (or role/permission info) with the ID of the documents in the sub-collection matching the requesting user's ID **(i.e. the security document must exist with the proper role/permission to access the parent document)**.

This doesn't solve all of the problems when designing the database structure, but it is a great starting point by helping to identify "naturally hierarchical" ([Choose a Data Structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data)) data.